Flutter how to make custom horizontal calender?
everyone
I'm trying to achieve that UI on the attached screens, but all I get into my brain is
Tabbar [Day, Week, Month, Year] but how to make a custom Calender that shows only 1 item by scroll that appear in the screenshot


or what is the best Idea to achieve that?
thanks for everyone
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 4,
  initialIndex: 0,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
        height: 200,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: secondryColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TabBar(
              dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey[300],
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
              tabs: const [
                Tab(text: 'Day'),
                Tab(text: 'Week'),
                Tab(text: 'Month'),
                Tab(text: 'Year'),
              ],
            ),
            const Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Replace these Text widgets with the content of your choice for each tab
                  DaysWidget(
                    type: "Expenses",
                  ),
                  Text("2"),
                  Text("3"),
                  Text("4"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);

